# HTTP Error 409: conflict urllib2 python

Tags: python, api, urllib2, http-error

I would like to iterate over a list of url api requests with different ?get variables (x1,....,xn).

```
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request
import pandas as pd

var=[x[0],...,x[n]]
url_list=['http://BLAH/get?var[0]&fmt=csv','http://BLAH/get?var[1]&fmt=csv',...      ...,'http://BLAH/get?var[n]&fmt=csv']

j=0
while j < len(url_list):
    req=Request(url_list[j])
    response=urlopen(req)
    df=pd.read_csv(response)
    print df
    j=j+1**
```

I have tried to del req and response.close() but my code still produces a conflict error.

```
 File "C:\Users\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
  return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
 File "C:\Users\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 410, in open
  response = meth(req, response)
 File "C:\Users\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
  'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
 File "C:\Users\nfitzsimons\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 448, in error
   return self._call_chain(*args)
 File "C:\Users\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
   result = func(*args)
 File "C:\Users\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
   raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    rllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 409: Conflict
```

Has anybody any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to iterate over a list of urls and print the contents upon a successful request, why not try this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

try:
    import requests
except ImportError as err:
    print("Woops, you're missing " + str(err))


urls = []

req = requests

for url in urls:
   response =  req.get(url)
   if response.status_code == 200: #Successful request
       print(response.content)
```

Comment: Thanks... This method does also work, :D But was not the problem. I had to add a time.sleep() function because I was trying to access too much at once!

Comment: Good to know! Side note that may affect you in the future. Some sites (Reddit) will give you a 409 error if you're crawling or accessing their site too frequently without a unique user-agent. Look into specifying user-agents if this happens to you!